# Template for Feature Edit Popup in GeoExplorer

Tags: editing, boundless-suite, geoexplorer, geonode

I need to customize GeoExplorer (OpenGeoSuite). I have to create an input mask for a point layer in editing (create and modify tools). 
When I insert a point, GeoExplorer shows a popup with attributes as in DB (Postgis) in a grid form. I'd like to let users choose between few values, using combobox, propose defaults for some attributes,  and so on.
I've found the Freemarker Template for identify ([GetFeatureInfo Template](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html)) and it's ok but I need something similar in editing.

I'm using GeoExplorer in Geonode

Answer (score 1):

To get domain values for layer attribute, follow below steps:

- create schema.xsd and place it in geoserver/data/workspace/yourworkspace/datastore/layer_name/
  example for file content :

  ```
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SIGNHEIGHT" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SIGNWIDTH" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SIGNSTYLE" nillable="true" >
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="R1-1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R1-2"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R1-3W"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R1-4W"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R2-1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R2-5C"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R3-1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R3-2"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R3-5L"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R3-5R"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R3-5a"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R3-7L"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R3-7R"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R3-16"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R4-7a"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R4-7b"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R5-1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R5-1a"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R5-2"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R5-2a"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R6-1(R)"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R6-1(L)"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R6-2(R)"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R8-3"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R10-6"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R10-11"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R10-11b"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R10-12"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R11-2"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R11-3a"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R11-4"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R12-5"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W1-1L"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W1-1R"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W1-2L"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W1-2R"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W1-3L"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W1-3R"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W1-4L"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W1-4R"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W1-5L"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W1-5R"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W1-6L"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W1-6R"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W1-7"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W1-8L"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W1-8R"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W2-1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W2-2L"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W2-2R"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W2-4"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W3-1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W3-2"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W3-3"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W4-5"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W6-1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W6-2"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W6-3"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W8-5"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W8-9"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W9-1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W9-2"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W9-2 alternate"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W10-1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W11-2"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W11-8"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W13-1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W14-1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W14-2"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W17-1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W20-2"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W20-3"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="W21-1a"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="G20-2"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M4-8a"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M4-9R"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M4-9L"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M1-4"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M1-5"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M2-1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M3-1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M3-2"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M3-3"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M3-4"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M4-5"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M5-1L"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M5-1R"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M5-2L"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M5-2R"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M6-1L"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M6-1R"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M6-2L"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M6-2R"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M6-3"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M6-4"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M6-6R"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M6-6L"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M6-7R"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M6-7L"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M6-8"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="M6-9"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="D1-1c"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="D7-1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="D7-2"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="D9-2"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="D9-6"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="D9-14"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="I-5"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Other"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Unknown"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SIGNTEXT" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="FACING" nillable="true">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="East"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="North"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="South"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="West"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Northeast"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Northwest"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Southeast"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Southwest"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="North/South"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="East/West"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Northeast/Northwest"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Southeast/Southwest"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="HORIZCLEAR" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="HORIZFROM" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="VERTFROM" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ANGLE" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="DISTTOTOP" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="REFLCOAT" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SHEETING" nillable="true">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="Type I (Engineer Grade)"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Type II (Super Engineer Grade)"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Type III (High Intensity)"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Type IV (Multi-Layer Sheeting)"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Type V (Metallized Microprismatic)"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Type VI (Vinyl Backed Microprismatic)"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Type VII (Microprismatic)"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Type VIII (Microprismatic- Distinguishing)"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Type IX (Fine Grain Microprisms)"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Type X (Microprismatic - Similar to Types VII-IX)"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Unknown"/>                  
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SUPMATERIA" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="INSTALLDAT" nillable="true" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CONDITION" nillable="true">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="Excellent"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Very Good"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Good"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Fair"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Poor"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Very Poor"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Unknown"/>                                  
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="OWNEDBY" nillable="true">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:int">
                <xsd:enumeration value="1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="-1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="-2"/>                                               
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="MAINTBY" nillable="true" >
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:int">
                <xsd:enumeration value="1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="-1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="-2"/>                                               
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="LASTUPDATE" nillable="true" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="LASTEDITOR" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:complexContent>
  ```
- reload geoserver configuration.
  attributes with enumeration values will have a drop down list in identify popup

for more information about [schema mapping](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/schemamapping.html)